# How do I call a userform button to be "clicked" from a different form

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 forms:

FrmDataEntry and FrmNotAllDataEntered

In FrmNotAllDataEntered I want to call the code in the button "CmdDataTurnIn" in FrmDataEntry to validate the new data entered in FrmNotAllDataEntered is accurate and populates to a worksheet (this code is in FrmDataEntry under the "CmdDataTurnIn_click" sub.

I have tried doing the following:

```
'This is in FrmNotAllDataEntered
GoTo CheckAgain

'This is in FrmDataEntry
CheckAgain:

'Code I want it to run
```

I have also tried:

```
'This is in FrmNotAllDataEntered

Call CmdDataTurnIn_click
```

I have also tried:

```
'This is in FrmNotAllDataEntered

Call FrmDataEntry.CmdDataTurnIn_click
```

None of the following works as the debug window pops up.

Answer (score 0):

When you have 2 forms that need the same validation logic, I usually create a method (placed in a module) that can be called from either form.  Something like this:

**FrmNotAllDataEntered**

```
Private Sub SomeMethodInFrmNotAllDataEntered()
   DataTurnIn
End Sub
```

**FrmDataEntry**

```
Private Sub CmdDataTurnIn_Click()
   DataTurnIn
End Sub
```

**Module1**

```
Public Sub DataTurnIn()
   'all the code cut and pasted from the click event
End Sub
```

Another option is to create a public method in FrmDataEntry.  Something like this:

**FrmNotAllDataEntered**

```
Private Sub SomeMethodInFrmNotAllDataEntered()
   FrmDataEntry.DataTurnIn
End Sub
```

**FrmDataEntry**

```
Private Sub CmdDataTurnIn_Click()
   DataTurnIn
End Sub

Public Sub DataTurnIn()
   'all the code cut and pasted from the click event
End Sub
```